# Showing that an ideal is not generated by two elements

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X=V(x_1, x_2)$ and $Y=V(x_3, x_4)$ be affine varieties on $\Bbb C^4$ where $\Bbb C$ is the complex number. Then, I have to show that the ideal $I(X ∪ Y)$ cannot be generated by two elements. I think I need to find some contradiction... Could anyone show me how to give a proof?

Comment: The ideal is the radical of the product of $(x_{1}, x_{2}), (x_{3}, x_{4})$. But the product of the ideals is in fact already a radical ideal. So $I(X \cup Y) = (x_{1}x_{3}, x_{1}x_{4}, x_{2}x_{3}, x_{2}x_{4})$. A computation with a contradiction argument should now be able to show you that this ideal cannot be generated by $2$ generators. The computation may be a little tedious though.

Comment: Could you show me more details about deriving a contradiction? I tried everything I could but, can't get a result...

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Monomial ideals, leading terms ( Groebner bases etc)

If $P_k$ generate a monomial ideal $I$ then the leading terms of $P_k$ will also generate $I$. But the minimal number of monomials generating $I$ is $4$.